# Show that $\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 \,\mathrm dx \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{\pi^2}\int_a^b |f'(x)|^2 \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Show that if $f \in C^1[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then $$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 \,\d x \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{\pi^2}\int_a^b |f'(x)|^2 \,\d x.$$

By a change of variable, it suffices to assume that $a=0$ and $b=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Extend $f$ to $\left[-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$ by setting $f(-x)=-f(x)$, then extend $f$ to be periodic on $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ thus extended is in $C^1(\mathbb{T})$.

$$\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)e^{-2ik\pi x} \,\d x=\frac{1}{ik\pi}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f'(x)e^{-2i\pi kx} \,\d x=\frac{1}{2i\pi k}\hat{f'}(k).$$

Now $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(k)|^2=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{4\pi^2k^2}|\hat{f'}(k)|^2\le \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f'}(k)|^2.$$

This gives us that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}|f(x)|^2 \,\d x \le \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|f'(x)|^2 \,\d x.$$

For the general case define $g:\left[0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(2(b-a)x+a)$. Then by the above we have $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|g(x)|^2\,\d x \le \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|g'(x)|^2\,\d x,$$ which gives that $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}|f(2(b-a)x+a)|^2\,\d x \le \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|f'(2(b-a)x+a)|^24(b-a)^2\,\d x.$$

Let $u=2(b-a)x+a$. Then $\d u=2(b-a)\,\d x$ and the integral changes to $$\int_{a}^b|f(u)|^2\,\d u \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{\pi^2}\int_a^b|f'(u)|^2\,\d u.$$

Comment: Are you missing some conditions? Because without the assumption that $f(a) = f(b)$, both the proof and the result are not valid in general.

Comment: @SangchulLee I am sorry. I missed a condition.

Comment: this is named as the Wintinger's inequality. I know it for $-\infty<f(a)=f(b)<\infty$

Comment: try to show that $\sum |\hat g|^2\le \sum |\hat g'|^2$

Comment: @Masacroso I feel that  I am missing something. Because, everything needed is there. There is integral of $f'$ on right and $\|f\|$ on left and all.

Comment: Idk exactly where is the mistake. What I did to prove this was changing the integral from $[a,b]\to[0,\pi]$ and after I extended the new function to $[-\pi,\pi]$ from where I get $$\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}|\hat g_k'|^2=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |g'|^2$$ from Parseval's theorem.

Comment: @Masacroso I see what you are saying.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be real-valued here?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes it is. I think I found the solution though

Comment: @Masacroso I think I found the answer. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't understand the identification though.

Comment: If you think of $\mathbb{T}$ as the unit circle in the complex plane, think of $g(e^{2 \pi it}) = f(t)$.  Verify that $g$ is well-defined and $C^1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not separating the series into $\sin$ ans $\cos$. It still works out pretty fine without it, guess

Comment: It is better to post an answer instead of putting your answer into the question. Now I see no question in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get rid of the constants. Take $a=0,b=\pi$ without loss of generality and extend f to $[-\pi,\pi]$ by making it odd. Since $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ this gives a $2\pi$ periodic function. The inequality becomes $\int_-\pi ^{\pi} |f(x)|^{2} dx \leq \int_-{\pi} ^{\pi} |f'(x)|^{2}dx$. In terms of Fourier coefficients $\{a_n\}$ this becomes $\sum |a_n|^{2} \leq \sum |n a_n|^{2}$ which is obvious.